# perl regex for {8} character string with decimal digits AND letters and nothing else

Tags: regex, string, perl

I'm trying to build a **Perl** regex that matches an **8 character** string that requires a **length of exactly 8** consisting of **at least one letter A-F** (uppercase) **AND** **at least one decimal digit (0-9)**

**I'd like the regex to catch:**

- A13B4D90
- 13CF928B
- A2F1C3D5

**But not:**

- 1392857
- 2962219
- 3945580
- ASFLEAN
- -MLQORNA

Right now I have

[\dA-F]{8}

and it's allowing all of the above. I don't want fields that are all digits or all letters- only want it to match ones with digits AND letters.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, can you write regexes for the other conditions as well? After that, we can join them into a single regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of lookaheads:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-F])[\dA-F]{8}$
```

`(?= ... )` makes sure there's a match ahead before continuing the match of the rest of the pattern,

`(?=.*\d)` basically makes sure there's a digit matching any number of characters from where the lookahead is, in this case from the start of the pattern.

`(=.*[A-F])` acts the same way, thus it acts as a check to make sure there's a letter between A and F somewhere ahead after any number of characters.

Comment: Depending on the circumstances, `\d` should be `[0-9]` instead.

Comment: PERFECT. I'll have to do some research on look aheads.

Comment: @user1694958 Could you please mark my answer as accepted? :) Also, I added a few more detail about the lookaheads.

Comment: Note that `$` (as opposed to `\z`) allows for a trailing newline.

Comment: @Jerry Your regex doesn't appear to work for `13CF928B` according to regexplanet's [Perl beta](http://fiddle.re/tkyyn) ( or its [Java tester](http://fiddle.re/0keyn) ).  I'm trying to learn from your answer and I'm trying to interpret the results from regexplanet.

Comment: @n0741337, looks like fiddle.re's implementation of Perl-compatible regular expressions, is not in fact Perl-compatible. Jerry's regexp works fine in Perl.

Comment: @n0741337 You have put a white space after `13CF928B` which naturally makes the string invalid :)

Comment: @Jerry - Thanks for looking!  Now I've learned to pay more attention to the subtle boxes from rexplanet's output as well as my copy/pasting :)